# Records between start and end date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am having two textfields which represents startDate and endDate.Now the problem I am facing is that I want all the records from the database which occured between this interval.But the field which stores date is TimeStamp and is of format :

```
24-APR-14 09.23.44.458000 PM or we can say dd-mm-yy hh.min.ss.milli AM/PM
```

Now obviously user entering the date is not going to enter it in such a format.So what should be query to select records from table say t1 between this date interval.

Comment: use BETWEEN keyword.. between date1 and date2

Comment: What is the datatype of these fields?  If they're DateTime you can just use the `BETWEEN` keyword.

Comment: The reason you get downvoted is that the question does not show enough effort, and it is also too unclear.

Comment: @Siyual their datatype is TimeStamp

Comment: @GordonLinoff Am using oracle10g as database

Answer (score 1):

Saving Date data as Date or Datetime makes life easy.
You have tagged Mysql in the question so here is a Mysql Solution.

This is what you can do

```
select * from
test
where
date_format(str_to_date(`date`,'%d-%b-%y'),'%Y-%m-%d') 
between '2014-04-15' AND '2014-04-24'
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0325/6)**

You can format the user input as you want in the query in DATE_FORMAT().

Comment: The date is of type TIMESTAMP and not a string.So please help

Comment: please update the demo and add your data and post the link here after you have updated the record and table.

Comment: The demo has no option for a datatype being a TIMESTAMP. am using oracle 10g by the way

Comment: ah thats the issue !! Why did you tagged it as Mysql then ? I am not expert in Oracle.My answer is based on Mysql. You may need to reply some questions being asked about that. Just nudge them by using @ followed by username, they will reply to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

User input will have a startdate and a enddate may be in datetime OR date variable

while trying to use these two input variables in the WHERE CLAUSE use BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) AND (CAST(@EndDate AS DATE) + 1)

This will fetch results that lies in both dates and the data range as well